# react-native PanResponder: OnMoveShouldSetPanResponder Not Working

Tags: react-native

I am working on a small project using React-Native PanResponder.

My Goal: I am trying to capture if the user is touching the screen, not moving around.

My Problem: I cannot run any code inside 
 `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState)`  in order to block PanResponder when the user only touches.

I tried `console.log` the param `gestureState` or a random string and it did not response.

my code:

```
    componentWillMount(){

        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({

        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
            // no console.log shown in this scope.
            console.log(gestureState);
            console.log("a string inside should set on move")
            // the PanResponder still works despite this returns false
            return false;
        },

        onPanResponderMove : (evt, gState) => {
            // this works perfectly. 
            this.setState({addAngle: this.state.addAngle + gState.vy*40});
        },

    })

}
```

My Question is: Am I missing anything here ? I saw the code snippets of others and they seem to be working very well.

where I saw the sample code: https://gist.github.com/teameh/dd055d546a3bd8f85b9516840e3a45f3

Tech:

- react-native cli (no expo)
- android API version 23 from Android Emulator (Android Studio)

Note: I have not tested on any Iphone device yet.

Cheers !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting onStartShouldSetPanResponder. I can't point to any documentation to support this but I believe that onStartShouldSetPanResponder and onMoveShouldSetPanResponder are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hello Tyler, you were right. I removed both "onStartShouldSet..." and the application worked ! There seem to be some conflicts if I use both "onStart" and "onMove" together. Thank you !

Comment: This did not work for me. I removed the all `onStartShould...` callbacks, but the function is not called in `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder ` callback

Comment: @David, did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: Nope @bmovement :(

Comment: Yeah, me either, @David

Comment: Maybe this will help you guys https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27988#issuecomment-652796228. Looks like Android can't have `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` fired all the time. I'm not sure about a source of that comments, but..

Or read this -  https://codedaily.io/tutorials/Maintain-Touchable-Items-with-a-Parent-PanResponder-in-React-Native (hope link will still lives)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture that was interfering with  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder, but it does capture too so that kinda makes sense.

One extra tip to bare in mind when you are debugging this stuff - remember that if you create your PanResponder using useRef, you will need to unmount and mount before your changes take effect.

Obvious i know - but it took me a while before i realised why my changes were not fast refreshing.